# Ansible winrm "credssp: 'module' object has no attribute 'TLSv1_2_METHOD

Tags: python, ansible

On my CentOS 7 box running Ansible 2.7.5, when I connect to windows machine using winrm getting below message.

```
TASK [ping] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f843379e230>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f844a45c6e0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
```

After looking online, upgraded pyOpenSSL package

```
 sudo yum install pyOpenSSL
 pyOpenSSL.x86_64 0:0.13.1-4.el7 will be installed
```

Now I am getting this error message.

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "credssp: 'module' object has no attribute 'TLSv1_2_METHOD'", "unreachable": true
```

How to resolve this error message?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have unlinstall these two python moduel and re-installed, it worked now.

```
sudo yum remove pyOpenSSL
sudo pip uninstall requests-credssp
sudo pip install requests-credssp
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: Also do not forget to remove and re-install pyOpenSSL via pip.